# Can I use my ubuntu server without a gfx card to render?

Tags: rendering

Can I use my ubuntu server without a gfx card to render?
I already got blender installed and when I tried to render a test file (cpu/cycles) I get multiple errors, file itself is ok, it renders fine on my laptop. So before I go bughunting it might be good to get an answer on my question :)

Much appreciated.

Comment: Sure. Set the device to CPU and render via command line https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/workflows/command_line.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have packaged your external assets with your .blend file, such that when referencing these assets you're looking for UV map images in, say, "//Assets/UVMaps/", you *should* be able to simply use the command line to render.  The trick is to use the `-b` (batch) switch:

`blender -b [file].blend`

which will give you headless (no GUI) operation.  Next up are a few command line options:

- `-S` : select the scene to be rendered
- `-a` : render the full animation (only applicable if you're doing an animation)
- `-f` : render a specific frame (should not be used with `-a`)
- `-F` : the output format to utilize (this may already be set up in your .blend)
- `-o` : save the rendered output to a specific file (not needed if you've already set this up in your .blend)

For a single frame of an animation, your command line may look like this:

`blender -b [file].blend -S [scene] -f [frame number] -F PNG -o frame_######.png`

For the full animation, your command line may look like this, assuming you've already set the format and output parameters in the .blend file:

`blender -b [file].blend -S [scene] -a`

Note that if your .blend has only one scene, or if you have saved your .blend such that the active scene is the one you wish to have rendered, `-S` is optional.

If you're still getting errors, to better diagnose what's going on I know that I for one will need to see what the actual error log is.